# Cannot display a legend with special character in highchart from the serie name

Tags: highcharts

I have a serie name with special character that I cannot change. How I can show it? I tried legend: { useHMTL: true }, but it's not working.

My code is here:

```
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
                        useHTML: true,
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        subtitle: {
                        useHTML: true,
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {

            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },

        legend: {

            title: {
                text: 'City<br/><span style="font-size: 9px; color: #666; font-weight: normal">(Click to hide)</span>',
            },
            layout: 'vertical',
            x: -10,
            y: 100
        },
        series: [{
            name: '<Tokyo>',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        },{
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4x6susks/

It isn't working to `<Tokio>` legend

Comment: What do you mean "cannot replace"? How about the same visual symbol written with different symbols? HTML entities is probably a common fix for this.

Comment: I cannot change the service that provide this string.

Comment: But can't you do html entity conversion before showing it in the chart?

Comment: I'm really looking for a solution inside the highchart option. I have a lot of issues if I just make this change before the option. But, I'm thinking that is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Replace in name: `<` with `&lt;`. Otherwise legend will use that name as tag (like `<span>` or `<div>`). See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4x6susks/3/

Comment: Hi Pawel, I'm trying a solution that don't change the string because it is provide from a external service.

Comment: You need to change it anyway.. In fact you can preprocess your names and do it before rendering chart.  In JS you can use `String.replace()` method. You can also use formatters in Highcharts, but you will need to use every one of them (in your case it's probably `tooltip.formatter` and `legend.labelFormatter`).